# valid URL to redirect to

Tags: node.js, express, http

I have a weird situation where I have a list of urls written by my users (sometimes with omitting https, e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or google.com), I would like to redirect to those URLs but I am not sure should I append "http://" or "https://", is there an accepted way or library to convert them to proper redirect links to use in express res.redirect("url").

Let me be more clear:

Here is a working express code:

```
res.redirect("http://www.google.com")
```

and the one I have with error:

```
res.redirect("google.com")
```

which redirects me to myhost/google.com. Question is, it doesn't matter how these URLs are written, if you copy and paste them to chrome address bar, they will work. I would like the same functionality in my redirects.

I am sorry if this is just too dumb to ask, I am kind of a newby in express and node.js

Answer (score 0):

You should `NOT` add the protocol to your link, ***if the link is a default website***, not `FTP` or any other resource. Indeed, `http` is obsolete and deprecated for a lot of browsers, and will be no longer for some browsers in short time. And this can be change in the future if SSL certificate become obsolete.

Anyway, you should add it in variable method (not hardcode way) by adding a function that you could modify at the future, something like:

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

or you could do it by database if you have that layer in your app. Then add the http or https to every link at DB layer.

Comment: Thank you for blazing fast answer. Help me out please, how can I handle this situation then? express.js is obviously not redirecting to for instance www.google.com

Comment: @KemalAcikgoz please see my update

Comment: @KemalAcikgoz and if my answers helps you please don't forget to upvote / mark it as correct :) Or ask me again if you have any doubt I will glad to update my answer :)

Comment: Hi, this answer is elaborate. Thank you very much. However, since I started using stackoverflow with a new user, I cannot upvote you. When I pass the mark 15 (currently at 11 :) ) I will come back and upvote your answer. P.S.: I found a library called parse-url in npm, it handles exactly what I need.